# Is it true that abortion is allowed if it endangers the mother's mental health?

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, pregnancy-birth, psych-mentalhealth, abortion

I heard this and it makes no sense because then almost every mother would have the excuse to abort; What would the exact parameters of such mental health issues be?

Comment: It has to be serious. Every pregnancy comes with side effects like morning sickness, but only serious health issues can justify ending a pregnancy. Same with mental health. Threshhold for serious is determined by a competent posek.

Comment: Mental health is in some cases Piquach Nefesh, life threatening. There are indeed a lot of cases Poskim allowed abortion for it.

Comment: Mental health is dealt with in the answers here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/39015/is-a-jew-permitted-to-have-an-abortion