# Many mamzerim today?

Tags: halacha, marriage, mamzer

In modern times, we go out of our way to make sure that we never find out that someone is a mamzer. For example, courts in Israel are very reluctant to order paternity tests for children for fear of it being discovered.  As a result of all of this--and the unfortunate prevalence of "cheating"--wouldn't we expect that many of the people who we treat as non-mamzerim actually are mamzerim?

There are also situations where children are born who are almost certainly mamzerim, but we bend over backwards to find a possible way that they are not (e.g. the husband returned home from Europe over night and had relations with the wife with neither of them remembering).

When we do things like this, don't we just facilitate the spreading of mamzeirus throughout the Jewish community? Wouldn't we expect that eventually, all Jews would be mamzerim chas v'shalom?

Comment: I object to your wording. Mamzerim are full-fledged Jews. They must follow Halachah like all others and have a share in 'Olam HaBa.

Comment: @SethJ Is this edit better?

Comment: Lo bashamayim hi.  Mamzers are only what we say they are.  If we define it out of existence, the class no longer exists.

Comment: Why not just say "non-Mamzerim"?  Or just leave out that clause altogether: "wouldn't we expect that many people are actually mamzerim?"

Comment: Can you source the fact that this is a modern innovation?

Comment: And can you find a source that cheating is more prevalent?

Comment: @DoubleAA I would not claim that this is a modern innovation; however, we do have some techniques for finding out now, like DNA testing, that were not available in the past. Yet we avoid using them.

Comment: @yirmeyahu It may or may not be more prevalent now, but it is prevalent.

Comment: @Daniel DNA testing, if done, would establish mamzerut?

Comment: @SethJ I have changed it as you suggested.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman So you say that we not only treat such people as non-mamzerim, but they actually are not mamzerim? A person can go from actually not being a mamzer to being a mamzer instantaneously upon discovering that his father is not the man married to his wife?

Comment: @DoubleAA According to [this site](http://www.family-laws.co.il/paternity-genetic-testing), it would. I believe some godol hador has ruled on this. I'll try to look it up.

Comment: @Daniel That's not exactly a strong Halachik source in my mind. Why don't you check out discussion we've had on Mi Yodeya here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9938/dna-and-jewish-law

Comment: @DoubleAA [Rav Elyashiv ruled](http://books.google.com/books?id=z9hZMs0SzxUC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=dna+mamzer+teshuva&source=bl&ots=1RkVPrx1hT&sig=pCiGurcmfj5vZb9PcK155yYQ1y0&sa=X&ei=URgtULuAN5SI6AGV84CgDA&ved=0CD8Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=dna%20mamzer%20teshuva&f=false) that DNA testing can establish mamzeirus

Comment: @Daniel Technically we can only deduce that he thinks it at least _might_ establish mamzerut.

Comment: We can prove via DNA that this person's biological father isn't his mother's husband, but that doesn't prove mamzerut because the biological father could be a non-Jew. Even if we can prove that this man's father is Joe the Jew (who was never married to this woman), it's not clear. Rabbi Breitowitz said he'd assume that would make mamzerut; Rabbi Mordechai Willig has posited it's still not clear proof, as maybe there was an artificial insemination (which, according to Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, doesn't create mamzerut either).

Comment: @shalom that is exactly the kind of somersault that I'm talking about to not find out that the child is a mamzer.

Comment: @Daniel Isn't it wonderful that we're willing to go to such great lengths to love and include each other in klal yisrael?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Absolutely. I'm just wondering what the end result will be. If people are actually unknowing mamzerim, wouldn't they be violating the negative commandment to not marry non-mamzerim?

Comment: @Daniel Why was that a somersault? Isn't that standard Halachik legal reasoning?

Comment: There's a shiur on yutorah from Rabbi Hershel Schachter where he explains that *knowledge* of mamzerut is what creates the prohibition. So if we don't know, we're just as happy ...

Comment: @Shalom That answers my question. Post that as an answer, if possible with a link to the shiur, and I will happily accept it.

Comment: @Shalom awesome.  That's just like tzaraat: [וְטִמְּאוֹ הַכֹּהֵן, צָרַעַת הִוא](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0313.htm#8)

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9018/what-evidence-is-required-to-indicate-mamzer-status

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman: close but not quite. It's the act of knowing (not a declaration) that generates the issur. Rabbi Schachter's other example was bringing a korban for finding out one had inadvertently entered the Temple while impure. If Shmerel doesn't know he was impure at the time, I have no obligation to tell him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Encyclopedia Judaica's discussion of Mamzerim in Jewish Law](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0013_0_13122.html). From there:

> In addition, the Mishnah cites a tradition that "Eliyahu will not come [in the future] to declare the pure, impure – nor to declare the impure, pure; nor to distance those who are near or to draw near those who were distanced, but only to distance those drawn near by force and to draw near those distanced by force" ([Eduyyot 8:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&pgnum=221)).
>
> [R. Obadiah of Bertinoro interprets](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&pgnum=222) the citation as meaning that Eliyahu will only distance those who are publicly known to be tainted but were forcibly intermingled among the Jewish People, "but where there is a tainted individual in a particular family, but this is not publicly known, owing to the family having intermingled [into the Jewish community], Eliyahu will let it remain so and let the family retain its presumption of legitimacy."
>
> This was the basis for the Rema's ruling (Sh. Ar., EH 2:5 [[translation here]](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch/Even_ha-Ezer/2)) that if a person learns that one of the progenitors of a particular family is tainted by mamzerut, he may not reveal this, "but rather he should allow the presumption of their legitimacy to remain intact, for all the families that have become assimilated into Israel are legitimate in the future."